# Crontab and python script

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

My python script: badlink.py (i used http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system('linkchecker -ocsv -Fcsv/badlinks.csv www.mysite.com')
```

My crontab task

```
*/2 * * * * /opt/badlink.py
```

the problem is that If I run directly

`python badlink.py` I got the output result

My question is why it does not work with cronjob task.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that issue is with linkchecker not being found in environment when running within os.system. Try giving absolute path to linkchecker.

Comment: sh: 1: /opt/linkchecker/: Permission denied When I git abs path to linkchecker

Comment: your tips give me an idea,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
   */2 * * * * python /opt/badlink.py
```